# Is the limit of uniformly integrable functions integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If $\left\{f_n\right\}$ are uniformly integrable and $f_n\overset{a.e.}{\rightarrow}f$ ($f$ measurable), is $f$ integrable? Can "uniformly integrable" be weakened to "integrable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes

   $\int \left|f\right|\overset{\mathrm{a}}{\leq}\liminf\int |f_n|\overset{\mathrm{b}}{<}\infty$

   a. [Fatou's
   lemma](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_Lemma_for_Integrals/Positive_Measurable_Functions)

   b. Uniform integrability $\implies$ $\sup \int |f_n|<\infty$ (e.g.
   [Klenke](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000472), Theorem 6.24i)
2. No, e.g. $f_n:=\mathbb{1}_{\left[-n,n\right]}$ (borrowed from Per Manne's comment below)

Comment: The answer to the second question is no. If $f_n(x)$ is the indicator function of the interval $[0,n]$ then each $f_n$ is integrable, but the limit is not.

Comment: @PerManne: Thanks.

Comment: what is definition of uniformly integrable?

Comment: Can we strengthen the result to say that the limit of uniformly integrable functions is uniformly integrable (as opposed to just integrable)?

Comment: I don't see how a. is proved.

Comment: @KopaLeo: I've corrected the proof. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: We have to be a little more careful on 1(b). For instance, if we are considering a measure space $X=\{x\}$ with $\mu(x)=1$, then it turns out that the family $\{f_n\}_n$ defined by $f_n=n$ is uniformly integrable but does not satisfy 1(b).

Answer (score 2):

Put $f_n(x) = n(n+1)I_{(1/n+1, 1/n)}$, $x\in[0,1]$.  Then $f_n\to 0$ in $[0,1]$ and the sequence of the $f_n$ is $L^1$-bounded.  However, $f_n\not\rightarrow 0$ in $L^1$ as $n\to\infty$, since $\|f_n\|_1 = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks. I can only mark one answer as correct so i'm going to mark my own, since this was the question i was principally interested in.

Comment: But this is an example of some integrable functions $f_n$ such that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere and $f$ is integrable. Hence not an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Evan's accepted answer is almost correct and useful in most cases. However, it's missing a bit of nuance that is actually rather important when discussing other theorems like the [Vitali Convergence Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem)

Regarding your first question:  The pointwise limit of uniformly integrable functions is only guarenteed to be integrable if their domain $E$ has finite measure. I am using $m(A)$ for any set $A$ to refer to Lebesgue measure.

As a counterexample in the case where $m(E) = \infty$, consider Per Manne's example. Set $E = [0, \infty)$ and $f_n = \chi_{[0, n]}$, the characteristic (indicator) function for $[0, n]$. The family $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable: given $\epsilon > 0$, set $\delta = \epsilon$. Then for a measureable set $A$, 
$$m(A) < \delta \implies \int_A |f_n| \le \int_A 1 < \delta = \epsilon$$

However, $f_n \to f \equiv 1$ pointwise on $E$, and $\int_E |f| = \infty$ so $f$ is not integrable.

In general, another condition called **tightness** is used to justify the integrability of a pointwise limit of functions on any domain. Specifically, a family of measurable functions $F$ on a domain $E$ is tight over $E$ iff $\forall \, \epsilon > 0$, there exists $E_0 \subset E$ such that $$\int_{E \setminus E_0} |f| < \epsilon \, \, \forall \, f \in F $$

The proof of this is very similar to what Evan Aad described earlier, with an extra trick: I've sketched it below.

1. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Given $\{f_n\}$ measureable, uniformly integrable, and tight on $E$ where $\{f_n\} \to f$ pointwise on $E$, there exists some measurable set $E_0$ with finite measure s.t. 
   $$ \int_{E \setminus E_0} |f_n| < \epsilon \text{ and by Fatou's Lemma } \int_{E \setminus E_0} |f| < \epsilon$$
2. We have now reduced the problem to showing $f$ is integrable over $E_0$, as

$$\int_E |f| = \int_{E \setminus E_0} |f| + \int_{E_0} |f|$$
As Evan pointed out, uniform integrability implies $\sup \int_{E_0} |f_n| < \infty$ as $m(E_0) < \infty$, and then Fatou's Lemma implies $\int_{E_0} |f| < \int_{E_0} |f_n| < \infty$, completing the proof.

As a remark, if $m(E) < \infty$, then any family of functions is obviously tight; this is why the pointwise limit of uniformly integrable functions is guarenteed to be integrable if their domain has finite measure.

In response to your second question: As has been mentioned above, the pointwise limit of integrable functions is not necessarily integrable on any domain. An example of this with a domain of finite measure is $f_n = n$ on $E = [0,1]$. Then ${f_n} \to f \equiv \infty$ pointwise and clearly $f$ is not integrable even though $\int_E |f_n| = n$ for any $n$.

Citation: I am drawing from Sections 4.6 and 5.1 in [Royden and Fitzpatrick, Real Analysis.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8120342801)

Answer (score 0):

**Notes on Additional Assumptions**

1. It should be noted that for this to be true, we need the hypothesis that $|f|<\infty$ a.e..

For example, if $(X,\mathfrak{m},\mu)$ is defined by $X=\{x\},\mathfrak{m}=\{\emptyset,X\},\mu(X)=1$, take $f_n:=n$.

2. It also should be noted that we also need the hypothesis that $\mu(X)<\infty$.

For example, if the measure space $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure $m$, take $f_n:=\chi_{[0,n]}$.

---

A proof assuming the following hypothesis :

> 1. $|f|<\infty$ (or only a.e. is also ok)
> 2. $\mu(X)<\infty$

can be given as follow.

**Proof**

By uniform integratability, find $\delta>0$ with $\mu(E)<\delta$ implies $\int_E|f_n|<1$. By Fatou, $\chi_Ef\in L^1(\mu)$.

Since $\mu(X)<\infty$, by successively cutting away these (can be taken to be finitely many) $E$, we may just assume now that every non-empty measurable subset of $X$ has measure $\geq\delta$.

In this case, notice for $x\in X$, $\mu(f^{-1}(f(x)))\geq\delta$, which shows that $f(X)$ is a finite set since $\mu(X)<\delta$, then the condition $|f|<\infty$ applied to each fiber of $f$ shows that $f\in L^1(\mu)$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Tao's blog contains an exercise stating that dominated convergence theorem extends to the uniformly integrable setting:

If ${f_n:X \rightarrow {\bf C}}$ is a sequence of uniformly integrable functions that converges almost everywhere to a function ${f: X \rightarrow {\bf C}}$, show that ${f}$ is absolutely integrable and ${\int_X f_n\ d\mu}$ converges to ${\int_X f\ d\mu}$.

Recall:
(Egorov’s theorem) Let ${X}$ have finite measure, and let ${f_n: X \rightarrow {\bf C}}$ and ${f: X \rightarrow {\bf C}}$ be measurable functions. Then ${f_n}$ converges to ${f}$ pointwise almost everywhere if and only if ${f_n}$ converges to ${f}$ almost uniformly.

Proof:

Evan's answer has shown that $f$ is absolutely integrable, by using Fatou's lemma and the uniform bound on $L_1$ norm for the $f_n$. It left to show that ${\int_X f_n\ d\mu} \rightarrow {\int_X f\ d\mu}$.

We'll show that ${|\int_X f\ d\mu - \int_X f_n\ d\mu| \leq \int_X |f - f_n|\ d\mu \rightarrow 0}$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since both the sequence $f_n$ and the constant sequence $g_n = f$ are uniformly integrable, by no escape to width or horizontal infinity there are finite measure subsets ${E}$ and ${F}$ of ${X}$ such that ${\int_{X \backslash F} |f|\ d\mu \leq \varepsilon/4}$ and ${\int_{X \backslash E} |f_n|\ d\mu \leq \varepsilon/4}$ for all ${n}$. Let $G = E \cup F$. Then:

$\begin{equation*} \int_X |f - f_n|\ d\mu = \int_{X \backslash G} |f - f_n|\ d\mu + \int_G |f - f_n|\ d\mu \tag{1} \end{equation*}$.

We control the two terms on the RHS separately. By construction, $\begin{equation*}
 \int_{X \backslash G} |f - f_n|\ d\mu \leq \int_{X \backslash G} |f|\ d\mu + \int_{X \backslash G} |f_n|\ d\mu \leq \varepsilon/4 + \varepsilon/4 = \varepsilon/2 \tag{2}
\end{equation*}$.

By Egorov's theorem, $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost uniformly on $G$. Let $K > 0$ be an upper bound of $|f - f_n|$ on $G$(guaranteed by the absolute integrability of $|f - f_n|$). Then there exists some $A \subset G$ with $\mu(A) \leq \varepsilon/4K$, such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly outside of $A$ on $G$. In particular, $\exists N > 0$, such that $|f(x) - f_n(x)| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4\mu(G)}$, $\forall x \in G \backslash A$, $\forall n \geq N$. Hence $\forall n \geq N$ we have:

$\begin{multline*}
 \int_G |f - f_n|\ d\mu = \int_{G \backslash A} |f - f_n|\ d\mu + \int_A |f - f_n|\ d\mu \leq \mu(G) \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{4\mu(G)} + K \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{4K} = \varepsilon/4 + \varepsilon/4 = \varepsilon/2. \tag{3}
\end{multline*}$

Combining inequalities $(2)$ and $(3)$ with equality $(1)$ gives the desired result.